# Get text from element using Selenium/WebDriver with PHP

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Is it possible to somehow get a value from an input that does not display the value in the source page?

Check screen: https://prnt.sc/1t2pnm8

Unfortunately, in this case the getText function does not work

`$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('//*[@id="list-overlay-form-wrapper"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/input'))->getText('');`

Comment: [Why not to upload images of code...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

You need to read `value` attribute of the element, not its text.

```php
$inputElement = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('ember171'));
$value = $inputElement->getAttribute('value');
```

For more examples have a look at [php-webdriver documentation](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver/wiki/Example-command-reference#get-attribute-of-an-element).